# C++ Impact Analysis tools

Tags: c++

Trying to search free tools for C++ impact analysis.
Google search is not helping much.
Could anyone suggest something?
Is that not a regular practice to do impact analysis for C++ source code?

Comment: Have you tried [ratchet](http://code.google.com/p/ratchet/)

Comment: Not able to download the same. I tried this : http://code.google.com/p/ratchet/downloads/list?can=1&q= and https://sites.google.com/site/clangratchetproject/home. You have link to download it?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeanalysistools.com/?cplusplus) might be of little help to you.